# Linux on ARM with Tegra 3

Tags: linux, eclipse, arm, tablet, tegra

I'm searching for a mobile device to program on. Up to now the natural choice would have been a laptop but with the new Tegra 3 cpus due next month and even windows 8 coming to arm next year I considered a shift of perspective. As a programmer I got lots of useful and important pdf files, courses for the university come as pdfs and ebooks about computer languages are almost more common than paperbacks. Certainly it would be more comfortable to read these on a tablet and with linux support on arm it might even be possible to code on a tablet. Tegra 3 certainly offers enough performance so there are my questions

- Has anyone ever used Linux on ARM and can tell me about potential
  problems?
- What about driver support? I've heard that nvidia releases
  official tegra drivers for arm but what about wlan etc. Any
  experiences / information?

and most important

- Do development tools work on ARM? I'm thinking about eclipse,
  netbeans,... I know that gcc and java-vm ports exist but couldn't get
  any precise information

Last but most important- No offence meant but frankly: I've learned that everything that involves Linux is bound to be difficult. Most if not all things on linux have to be configured and tested for hours on end - I admit that I'm no linux guru.

I won't mind some set-up difficulties and can cope with a little tweaking and a few workarounds but all in all I'm looking for a productive system.

Do you think a tablet running linux can be productive and stable enough to make programming enjoyable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is Linux.

```
$ uname -a
Linux fedoraplug.local 2.6.36.2 #1 PREEMPT Sat Dec 11 06:38:22 MST 2010 armv5tel armv5tel armv5tel GNU/Linux
$ yum list 'eclipse-*' 'java-1.*' 'gcc-*'
Installed Packages
gcc.armv5tel                            4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 @fedora
Available Packages
eclipse-anyedit.noarch                  2.2.0-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-birt.noarch                     2.5-1.fc12                       fedora 
eclipse-checkstyle.noarch               4.0.1-14.fc12                    fedora 
eclipse-cmakeed.noarch                  1.1.4-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-demos.noarch                    0.0.1-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk.noarch                     1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-itcl.noarch                1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-mylyn.noarch               1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-rse.noarch                 1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-ruby.noarch                1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-sdk.noarch                 1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-tcl.noarch                 1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dltk-xotcl.noarch               1.0.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-dtp.noarch                      1.7.0-5.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-eclemma.noarch                  1.4.2-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-eclox.noarch                    0.8.0-3.20090616svn.fc12         fedora 
eclipse-egit.noarch                     0.5.0-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-emf.noarch                      2.5.0-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-emf-examples.noarch             2.5.0-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-emf-sdk.noarch                  2.5.0-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-emf-xsd.noarch                  2.5.0-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-emf-xsd-sdk.noarch              2.5.0-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-epic.noarch                     0.6.35-2.fc12                    fedora 
eclipse-findbugs.noarch                 1.3.9-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-findbugs-contrib.noarch         4.0.0-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-gef.noarch                      3.5.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-gef-examples.noarch             3.5.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-gef-sdk.noarch                  3.5.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-moreunit.noarch                 1.3.3-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn.noarch                    3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn-java.noarch               3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn-pde.noarch                3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn-trac.noarch               3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn-webtasks.noarch           3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-mylyn-wikitext.noarch           3.2.1-2.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-nls.noarch                      3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-ar.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-bg.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-cs.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-da.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-de.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-el.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-en_AA.noarch                3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-en_AU.noarch                3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-es.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-et.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-fi.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-fr.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-he.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-hi.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-hu.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-it.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-ja.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-ko.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-mn.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-nl.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-no.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-pl.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-pt.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-pt_BR.noarch                3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-ro.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-ru.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-sv.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-tr.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-uk.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-zh.noarch                   3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-nls-zh_TW.noarch                3.5.0.v20090620043401-2.fc12     fedora 
eclipse-photran.noarch                  5.0.0-0.4.200910081739.fc12      fedora 
eclipse-photran-intel.noarch            5.0.0-0.4.200910081739.fc12      fedora 
eclipse-photran-xlf.noarch              5.0.0-0.4.200910081739.fc12      fedora 
eclipse-phpeclipse.noarch               1.2.1-5.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-quickrex.noarch                 3.5.0-12.fc12                    fedora 
eclipse-rpmstubby.noarch                0.3.0-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-rse.noarch                      3.1-2.fc12                       fedora 
eclipse-shelled.noarch                  1.0.4-4.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-slide.noarch                    1.3.13-2.fc12                    fedora 
eclipse-subclipse.noarch                1.6.5-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-subclipse-graph.noarch          1.6.5-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-svnkit.noarch                   1.3.0-1.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-systemtapgui.noarch             1.0-8.fc12                       fedora 
eclipse-testframework.noarch            3.5.0-3.fc12                     fedora 
eclipse-veditor.noarch                  0.6.3-4.fc12                     fedora 
gcc-c++.armv5tel                        4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 fedora 
gcc-gfortran.armv5tel                   4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 fedora 
gcc-java.armv5tel                       4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 fedora 
gcc-objc.armv5tel                       4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 fedora 
gcc-objc++.armv5tel                     4.4.2-5.fc12.fa4                 fedora 
java-1.5.0-gcj.armv5tel                 1.5.0.0-29.fc12                  fedora 
java-1.5.0-gcj-devel.armv5tel           1.5.0.0-29.fc12                  fedora 
java-1.5.0-gcj-javadoc.armv5tel         1.5.0.0-29.fc12                  fedora 
java-1.5.0-gcj-src.armv5tel             1.5.0.0-29.fc12                  fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk.armv5tel             1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.armv5tel        1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.armv5tel       1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.armv5tel     1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-plugin.armv5tel      1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src.armv5tel         1:1.6.0.0-31.b16.fc12.fa1        fedora
```

May want to get a separate keyboard and mouse for your own sanity while developing though.

Comment: what device are you using ? any major problems ? what about driver support

Comment: My device is a Pogoplug, so I can't really speak on the driver bits.